# Test component with context and react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a simple Dashboard component that relies on React context to manage auth. It contains a custom hook `useAuth` to extract the current user as well as the auth related functions: login, logout, etc.

This is the Context file: `AuthContext.js`:

```js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { auth } from "../config/firebase";

const AuthContext = createContext();

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  function signup(email, password) {
    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  function login(email, password) {
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  function logout() {
    return auth.signOut();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    signup,
    login,
    logout,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

This is the `Dashboard.js` component:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../context/AuthContext";

export default function Dashboard() {
  const { currentUser, logout } = useAuth();
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    setError("");
    try {
      await logout();
      history.push("/login");
    } catch (e) {
      setError(e.message);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {error && <p>{error}</p>}
      <h1>This is the Dashboard</h1>
      <h5>Email: {currentUser.email}</h5>
      <button onClick={handleLogout} type="button">
        Logout
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As recommened by [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/) I have created a test-utils.js file:

```js
import React, { createContext } from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

const AuthContext = createContext();

const currentUser = {
  email: "abc@abc.com",
};

const signup = jest.fn();
const login = jest.fn();
const logout = jest.fn();

const AllTheProviders = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser, signup, login, logout }}>
        {children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    </Router>
  );
};

const customRender = (ui, options) => {
  render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options });
};

export * from "@testing-library/react";

export { customRender as render };
```

However, when running `Dashboard.test.js` I get error

```js
    TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'currentUser' of '((cov_5mwatn2cf(...).s[0]++) , (0 , _AuthContext.useAuth)(...))' as it is undefined.

      4 | 
      5 | export default function Dashboard() {
    > 6 |   const { currentUser, logout } = useAuth();
        |           ^
      7 |   const [error, setError] = useState("");
      8 |   const history = useHistory();
```

```js
import React from "react";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import { act, render, screen } from "../config/test-utils-dva";

beforeEach(async () => {
  await act(async () => {
    render(<Dashboard />);
  });
});

test("displays dashboard", () => {
  expect(screen.getByText(/dashboard/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I think it is because Dashboard component is trying to use `useAuth` from `AuthContext.js`, how can I force the rendered Dashboard component to use the mocked data that I am sending in the `test-utils.js`file?

Comment: Instead of creating a new context, use the `AuthContext` from `context/AuthContext` for `<AuthContext.Provider>`, as that's the context that the hook uses.

Comment: such a simple solution, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Let me add that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creating a new context, use the `AuthContext` from `context/AuthContext` for `<AuthContext.Provider>`, as that's the context that the hook uses.

So, in `AuthContext.js`, export the context instance:

```js
export const AuthContext = createContext();
```

Then, in your `test-util.js` file, instead of again calling `createContext` (which will create a completely separate context instance - the contexts are not the same even if they are stored in a variable with the same name!), just import the previously exported instance:

```
import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";

const AllTheProviders = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser, signup, login, logout }}>
        {children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: Uh... and how would I do that?

Comment: @musicformellons I've clarified my answer - let me know if there's still something to improve.

Comment: more info: https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/#custom-render